# vary bubble size and color in CartoDB Torque Cat

Tags: carto, torque

I'm trying to make an animated map using the Torque Cat feature in CartoDB editor.

But I could not figure out how to edit the cartoCSS to vary both bubble size and color based on my dataset. I want to vary the bubble size based on a column with numbers (number of A), and also vary the color based on another column with strings (country name).

According to the [documentation](http://t.sidekickopen54.com/e1t/c/5/f18dQhb0S7lC8dDMPbW2n0x6l2B9nMJN7t5XYgd7lhdW8r4-m43M2pxPVQBb2Y56dz_8f8d0Lxx02?t=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2FCartoDB%2Ftorque%2Fwiki%2FHow-spatial-aggregation-works&si=6049575146618880&pi=67af5201-2a66-4164-a972-afa58e16df87), it is not possible to use more than one column.

> cluster does not contain values for all the columns, you can only use
>   value variable you would need to use an aggregation function for
>   strings

A [blog post](http://andrewxhill.com/blog/2015/04/17/torque-unknown/) by CartoDB's Andrew Hill on Torque examples did not address such issue too.

Anyone has experience working on this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create new categories based upon two-variable conditions.

Apply a query like this one:

```
SELECT 
  cartodb_id,
  time_column,
  the_geom_webmercator,
  numbers,
  categories
  CASE
    WHEN categories LIKE 'cat1' AND numbers <50 THEN 1
    WHEN categories LIKE 'cat1' AND numbers >=50 THEN 2
    WHEN categories LIKE 'cat2' AND numbers <50 THEN 3
    WHEN categories LIKE 'cat2' AND numbers >=50 THEN 4
    WHEN categories LIKE 'cat3' AND numbers <50 THEN 5
    WHEN categories LIKE 'cat3' AND numbers >=50 THEN 6
    END new_cat
FROM
  table
```

Creating a new dataset from that query would improve further performance.

You could then create a 'Torque Cat' visualization, based on `new_cat` column. This wizard uses the `CDB_Math_Mode()` to get the most repeated value in the grid cell, and passes it as `value`.

Then, adding as many CartoCSS rules as you need, you could style the map to your needs.

```
Map {
-torque-frame-count:256;
-torque-animation-duration:30;
-torque-time-attribute:"actor_postedtime";
-torque-aggregation-function:"CDB_math_mode(new_cat)";
-torque-resolution:8;
-torque-data-aggregation:linear;
}

#layer{
  comp-op: lighter;
  marker-fill-opacity: 0.9;
  marker-line-color: #FFF;
  marker-line-width: 0;
  marker-line-opacity: 1;
  marker-type: ellipse;
  marker-width: 6;
  marker-fill: #0F3B82;

  [value=1]{
    marker-fill:red;
    marker-width:10
  }
  [value=2]{
    marker-fill:red;
    marker-width:15;
  }
  [value=3]{
    marker-fill:blue;
    marker-width:10;
  }
  [value=4]{
    marker-fill:blue;
    marker-width:15;
  }
  [value=5]{
    marker-fill:yellow;
    marker-width:10;
  }
  [value=6]{
    marker-fill:yellow;
    marker-width:15;
  }

}
#layer[frame-offset=1] {
 marker-width:8;
 marker-fill-opacity:0.45; 
}
#layer[frame-offset=2] {
 marker-width:10;
 marker-fill-opacity:0.225; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Ernesto got the idea. The same new_cat can also be created beforehand in spreadsheet before uploading to CartoDB.