# make Carto torque points change over time start from begin date and disappear at end date

Tags: carto, cartography, cartocss, date, torque

First time use the torque function... I have variables: IDnumber,start_date, end_date, size, longitude, latitude.

Anyone know how to make carto torque points change depends on different dates?
I want to show the point on start dates, and make it disappear on its end date.

also I want to make each point size different depends on its size value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Torque](https://carto.com/torque/) aggregates data points according to a timestamp variable. So first, you need to collect all your date columns into one (for instance, `new_date`). As I understand from your question (and correct me if I am wrong), you only have two. If you want to generate more, you can use some of the SQL queries suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113469/generating-time-series-between-two-dates-in-postgresql).

But if you are just interested in showing the starting and ending point, choose the `new_date` as the `Time Column` within the Wizard in the CARTO Editor and voilá! One point will appear and disappear and then another point will appear and disappear (I recommend you to low the `Duration` to few seconds).

Finally, in relation to setting the `marker-width` according to column value, you can find [here](http://andrewxhill.com/blog/2015/04/17/torque-unknown/) how to do it. But basically, you will need to set `torque-aggregation-function` to `sum(size)` and add these lines at the end of the autogenerated CartoCSS code:

```
#layer[value=20]{
  marker-width: 20;
}
#layer[value=40]{
  marker-width: 40;
}
```

And you will end up with a map like this:

[image]

Comment: Hi! I will add more info: each ID has a start date and an end date. I want to show the points when they start and let them disappear when they end...ummm, does it make sense? I was able to show them timely by using -torque-time-attribute:"start_date"; but it won't disappear as they hit the end dates....is there a way to do that?

Comment: You have to collapse both column dates into one anyway. That's how Torque works. And then you can categorize your markers according to their `IDnumber` as explained [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/195883/vary-bubble-size-and-color-in-cartodb-torque-cat).

Comment: Ohhh, I got your point....I am going to try it! thank you! ^.^

Comment: I checked the time range site, it confuses me..in my case,  I have begin date from 2013.7.1-2016.3.5, and my end date range is from 2015.2.4 to 2017.11.30 ...what date range should I generate in order to combine these two column dates?

Comment: if you have time, can you take a look at my original dataset? I still not quite understand this method... https://tracyxlly.carto.com/tables/geo_info/public

Comment: The easiest way to do it (but maybe not the most efficient one) is to create two different datasets, one with the starting date and another with the ending data, and then joining them. It would be something like this: `SELECT cartodb_id, idnumber, i_date, size FROM geo_info` then create a new dataset from query (for instance, dataset1), and `SELECT cartodb_id, idnumber, e_date, size FROM geo_info` and create a new dataset from query (dataset2). Finally, in order to join them you should run this `SELECT * FROM dataset 1 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM dataset2`.

Comment: Anyway, because you are new to CARTO I highly recommend passing all the courses of the [Map Academy](https://carto.com/academy/). This will help you a lot working with SQL and CartoCSS.

Comment: ohhhhh, didn't know about this courses, thx for all the suggestions!!!

Comment: Please if you think your 1st question has been solved, mark it as answered.